# Checking for extraneous blank lines when creating objects from a text file

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, ioexception

I'm trying to create Student objects by reading from a given text file, but the text file has a bunch of empty blank lines under the actual info. I am not allowed to edit the text file in any way, and am also not allowed to use any other methods besides scanner for reading from the file. Everything works fine until I get to the bottom of the file, where a `NoSuchElementException`is thrown and the code fails.

```
        ArrayList<Student> Students = new ArrayList<>();
        while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
            Student student = new Student(fileIn.next(), fileIn.next(), fileIn.nextInt());
            student.setExam1(fileIn.nextInt());
            student.setExam2(fileIn.nextInt());
            student.setExam3(fileIn.nextInt());
            Students.add(student);
            fileIn.nextLine();
            System.out.println(student.toString());
        }
```

The file looks like this

```
Peck    CSI1000 12345   97  76  72
Rhodes  CSI1000 87649   98  70  73
Rinke   CSI1000 87649   78  70  78
Romanski    CSI1000 87649   84  84  95
Rombach CSI1000 12345   82  86  96
Ruan    CSI1000 87649   70  94  76
Ruc CSI1000 87649   97  98  80
Scott   CSI1000 87649   90  80  73
Shah    CSI1000 87649   98  72  71
Teal    CSI1000 87649   89  72  99
Tingley CSI1000 87649   76  85  72
Towne   CSI1000 87649   71  71  100
Tucker  CSI1000 12345   89  71  93
Ureel   CSI1000 87649   76  80  99
Wallace CSI1000 87649   76  100 71
Weber   CSI1000 87649   75  73  75
Wierszewski CSI1000 12345   93  90  72
Wilmot  CSI1000 12345   85  96  74
Wilson  CSI1000 12345   91  75  97
Yang    CSI1000 87649   83  80  85
Yasoni  CSI1000 87649   78  90  76
```

Comment: is it just blank lines at the END of the file, if so you could just catch the exception

Comment: @JRowan sorry, this is for a uni class, how do you do that? But yes it's just at the end.

Comment: I just posted an answer, you catch the exception so that way it won't crash if any requirements are not met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to catch the exception

```
    ArrayList<Student> Students = new ArrayList<>();
            while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
            try{
                Student student = new Student(fileIn.next(), fileIn.next(), fileIn.nextInt());
                student.setExam1(fileIn.nextInt());
                student.setExam2(fileIn.nextInt());
                student.setExam3(fileIn.nextInt());
                Students.add(student);
                fileIn.nextLine();
                System.out.println(student.toString());
            }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
                //break;
                fileIn.nextLine();

                System.out.println("exception");
            }
            }
```

or you can just `break` inside the catch block if after the exception you aren't expecting any more information anyway